# "insert" new row at lowest identity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a somewhat ugly problem of dealing with an existing database.  This database has a `Transaction_Items` table that contains the line items for each transaction (simplified):

```
Transaction_Item_ID(Identity - Auto)  Transaction_ID   Item_Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1                                      12345            Service1
2                                      12345            Service2
3                                      12345            Service3
4                                      12346            Service1
```

These transactions show up on an invoice and the application always orders them on that invoice based on the `Transaction_Item_ID`.

I need to add a service item to particular transactions that will always appear first, let's call its item name `MEMO`.  Otherwise the items need to remain in the same order. Therefore this `MEMO` item will always need to have the lowest `Transaction_Item_ID` out of those that match the transaction. Because `Transaction_Item_ID` is an auto identity column I cannot just change that to a lower value. I think I basically need to update the first row's `Item_name` to `MEMO` while copying the existing item name to the next lowest row and so on until the previous last row value is inserted into a new row.

The question is how to do this or if there is a better way of achieving the same result.

Basically ending like this:

```
Transaction_Item_ID(Identity - Auto)  Transaction_ID   Item_Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1                                      12345            MEMO
2                                      12345            Service1
3                                      12345            Service2
4                                      12346            Service1
5                                      12345            Service3
```

EDIT To clarify: I do not have access to change the application that is otherwise using this table.  I cannot add a new column to the table.

I know that the identity value cannot/should not be changed as that would cause a mess.  That is why I assume the only answer would be to "move" the Item name value "down" the rows.

Yes, this is ugly and far from ideal.  Unfortunately dealing with legacy applications and making the best of it is a reality in many businesses.  At least I actually have read/write access to the database.

Comment: This isn't really something that should be done, IMO. You should really just alter the query that is pulling data from the table to have a custom order by statement. e.g. `order by case when item_name = 'memo' then 0 else 1 end, transaction_item_id`

Comment: Why don't you insert that with a value of `-1` for the `transaction_item_id`?

Comment: You **cannot** update an existing value in an `identity` column - SQL Server allows you to **insert** specific custom values with the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` command , but you can **never** update an existing `identity` column's value.

Comment: If you're building a dependency on the numeric value of identity columns, I'd suggest you're doing something wrong. Treat them as opaque blobs that happen to fit in numeric columns and things will work. Anything else is asking for trouble. If you want columns which you can reliably use for ordering and where you can reorder rows, I'd suggest you need to add those as an explicit, non-IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your idea of updating each row.

Your simplest solution in this scenario is to rename this table and use it as a staging table, then perform an insert into a new table (which has the name your original table used to have) using the desired ordering.

Or, change the ordering in the application.

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit.  I don't have access to change the application or alter the table.  The joys of legacy software from dead companies.

Comment: What DB rights do you have then?  Check your user/AD login on the DB (In SSMS: Go to db folder where data is held -> security -> users ->right click on your login/AD group -> properties -> membership)

Comment: Not a rights issue on that database.  The issue is I cannot change the application accessing that data, which means any database changes are likely to throw it off.  If I rename and replace as you recommend there are likely to be issues as the application will still be trying to access that table and write new rows of its own.

Comment: How is data loaded into the table the application reads?  Does the application do it?

The way I have suggested to you is  the only sensible way to achieve this. If you insert rows into the table now, they will just be given the highest ID number on the identity row, so I would really recommend you get yourself db_owner rights to script it.  I can help you with that script if you need.

Comment: I have db_owner rights on that whole database.  The issue is that the service items are added by the application.  Basically one team adds in services to a new transaction as those services are rendered (application writes rows to this table for each service).  Then later an invoice is generated by the application based on those service items.  I need to "insert" that memo in between the application adding the service rows and reading them for the invoice.  Other new service items are being added all the time, so taking that table out of commission even temporarily wont work.

Comment: I suppose a trigger on that table for inserts might work.  Though not sure how much of a performance hit with the logic required.

Comment: You won't be able to get order of the identity columns you say you need in your original post if you need to add the memo between the service items and the read.

Comment: Not with a straight insert.  Thats why I was looking at storing the value of the lowest identity row, updating it to the memo, then place the stored value in identity row two and so on, finally inserting a new row with the stored values of the last original row.